# Use Fragment Listener without implementing in parent activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, interface, actionlistener

I have three fragments and one activity. When user starts and app, first fragment with map and Markers (F1) on it shows in activity. User clicks on one of the markers, second fragment (F2) shows with some other options. When user chooses specific option in F2, listener fires and delivers data to Main Activity. Then, Main activity needs to show third fragment (F3) and call one of his methods.Now, if that method is called before onViewCreated happens, it throws NullPointerException on specific fields (logically).

How can I implement way of saying MainActivity to call F3 when onViewCreated happens, or in the moment when these specific fields become not nulls, without implementing another interface in MainActivity (will be complicated because I already have enough interfaces implemented in it).

Is there some other way of accomplishing this?

Comment: You could call `fragment.isResumed()` from your `Activity` or something like that (`isVisible()`,..)before calling your `Fragment` method, if `false`, wait some time and try again?

Comment: @Amy Wait 'some' time?

Comment: You should only call a Fragment method interacting with UI when it is build  - so if your method call gets "time critical" a small `wait(100)` should suffice. Another idea, but not sure if it works: You could try to set a `flag` in your `Fragment`, set it to true when UI is build, and in your method, maybe a `while(!flag)` with `wait`...

Comment: Makes sense... I will try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass some parameter to F3 while creating the fragment and then in onCreateView motehod check the parameter call the method.

Comment: As you say, you can set a listener and the call the listener method in onCreateView or put some parameter to fragment's bundle and read that parameters back from bundle.

Comment: I did as you suggested. Another problem happening, but it isn't for this question. Thanks.